# Plotting a specific index range, in python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting **bitcoin data** and want to plot a range of index. My index is **Timestamp** and I have a single column **Price**.

in[]:

```
df.head()
```

out[]:

```
                 Price
Timestamp   
2017-04-02  1099.169125
2017-04-03  1141.813000
2017-04-04  1141.600363
2017-04-05  1133.079314
2017-04-06  1196.307937
```

what should I do to **plot** from the range **2018-03-15** to **2018-12-15**:

Answer (score 0):

You should use **.loc[]** function on df **dataframe** to specify range, whether it's simply **int** i.e. *0...n*, **date** i.e. *2018-03-15* or **char** i.e. *London....n* etc.

**for example**: in your case we will write it as,

```
df.loc['2018-03-15':'2018-12-15'].plot(title = 'Bitcoin range')
```